# Is there a way to call a pl/sql packaged procedure from WebSphere cast iron..?

Tags: oracle, plsql, websphere, cast-iron

I am working in a cross platform team, and trying to use a PL/SQL packaged procedure from Websphere Cast Iron, i am able to call standalone procedures but not packaged ones, if you have worked on a similar requirement, please advise.

Comment: No idea, I don't use that *Websphere" thing, but - how exactly do you call that PL/SQL procedure which exists in a package?

Comment: to call a procedure within a package, just use the convention: <PACKAGE_NAME>.<PROCEDURE_NAME>;

Comment: That's what I would expect, yes. What happens when you do so? Did you get any error? Which one?

Comment: when i search in the Cast iron it only shows Procedures outside packages, not the ones which are inside a package

Comment: In packages, procedures can exist **only in package body** (and are - therefore - **private** to that package). Or, they can be **exposed** to "public" if they are also declared in **package specification**. What about those procedure (the ones you'd like to execute)? Are they contained in the package specification? If not, try to include them in there.